# call child class method without call parent class

Tags: java, oop

I want to call this function without using its parent name:

```
Square square = new Square(Color.Blue, Pattern.DOTTED, 4);
```

but its error and said use this:

```
Square square = new Square(Shape.Color.Blue, Shape.Pattern.DOTTED, 4);
```

I want do this without import Shape calss and its method in main

The class is implemented as:

```
public class Shape {
    Color color;
    Pattern pattern;

    public Shape(Color c, Pattern p) {
        this.color = c;
        this.pattern = p;
    }
    enum Color {
        BLUE, GREEN, RED
    }
    enum Pattern {
        DOTTED, STRIPED, ZIGZAG
    }
}


public class Square extends Shape {

    Integer length;
    Shape shape = new Shape(Color.BLUE,Pattern.DOTTED);

    public Square(Color c, Pattern p, int length) {
        super(c, p);
        this.length = length; // autoboxing
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [Static Import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)?

Comment: ´Shape´ and ´Color´ are of ´protected´ access level (the default one if none is provided). Hence, they can only be accessed from its class or one of its subclasses. Make them public in the parent class and they will be accessible without the class name.

Comment: @Victor - Actually the default is `package private` but the rest of your suggestion might help a little.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. `Package private` is the default one and its a bit more restrictive than `protected`. Typed too fast! :)

Comment: This is definitely a case where showing the `package` and `import` lines would have made things much clearer, as well. These two classes cannot be in the same file as shown here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to define the enum outside the shape class

```
public class Shape {
    Color color;
    Pattern pattern;

    public Shape(Color c, Pattern p) {
        this.color = c;
        this.pattern = p;
    }
enum Color {
     BLUE, GREEN, RED
}
 enum Pattern {
     DOTTED, STRIPED, ZIGZAG
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your imports, you have there something like this:

```
...
import <package_name>.Shape;
...
```

Just change it to:

```
...
import <package_name>.Shape.Color;
...
```

Even if both `Shape` and `Square` are in the same package thus you don't have the import for `Shape` at all, adding this import will do the job.

You have to declare explicitly the imports for nested classes.
Perhaps your IDE does not autocomplete the imports of nested classes by default.